# Relationship b/w Circuit and Time Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am trying to understand Circuit Complexity's relation to classical Time Complexity. Here is what wiki mentions:

"If a certain language, ${\displaystyle A}$, belongs to the time-complexity class ${\displaystyle {\text{TIME}}(t(n))}$ for some function ${\displaystyle t:\mathbb {N} \to \mathbb {N} }$, then ${\displaystyle A}$ has circuit complexity ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {O}}(t(n)\log t(n))}$."

I find it quiet unclear. Here is my doubt:

Let $t(n)$ be a function that represents the exact (worst case) runtime of an optimal algorithm for some language $A$ on a Turing Machine ($n$ being the input size). What is the circuit size upper bound we expect for this program?

The big O notation simply says ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {O}}(t(n)\log t(n))}$ but this doesn't explain anything about the upper bound on the size of the circuit for an $n$ bit input. In bit O notation we have simply don't care about the actual value of the constants so this doesn't seem to be helpful. Can someone please explain?

**Query:** Given the description of the Turing Machine (lets call it $M$ and that can be simulated on a UTM) that decides the language $A$, how can we calculate the actual circuit size upper bound for a $n$ bit input to $M$ and not just the 'rate of growth' as described above?

Answer (score 1):

Circuit complexity refers to a family of circuits used to solve different inputs of the same problem. For a problem $A$, it is defined as a function $c : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for any integer $n$, there exists a circuit of size $\leqslant c(n)$ that decides all instances of $A$ of length $n$.

Given a function $t$ such that $A\in \mathsf{TIME}(t(n))$, what "circuit complexity $\mathcal{O}(t(n)\log t(n))$" means is that there exists a constant $\alpha > 0$ such that $A$ has circuit complexity $\alpha t(n) \log t(n)$.

Now sure you could get an upper bound with a very big constant $\alpha$ here, but what is important here is that $\alpha$ does not depend on the size of the inputs you are trying to decide. That means that even if $\alpha = 10^{100}$, there exists a circuit of size $\leqslant 10^{100}t(10^{10000})\log(t(10^{10000}))$ that decides inputs of length $10^{10000}$.

That is why the big-Oh notation here isn't a problem to link time complexity and circuit complexity.

Comment: Thank you. See I understand the concept of big O notation, the concept and how its definition is related to circuit complexity here. What I am unclear about and struggling with is why is the constant not defined or cannot be defined [P.S. what do we mean by 'choosing the constant..' here means]? The definition using the big O notation surely will tell us about the 'rate of growth' of the circuit size with $n$ but not the precise upper bound on the 'size of circuit' for a given $n$ even if we are given a specific function that defines the runtime of a particular algorithm (denoted by $t(n)$)?

Comment: For example: given a specific function $t(n)$ for a language $A$ say $n(log(n)$ we can input $n$ and see the worst case runtime or number of steps in the worst case. But, the big O notation will only tell us about the 'rate of growth' of the circuit size without giving any indication what the upper bound for an $n$ input circuit size is? I am interested in the circuit size upper bound and not the 'rate of growth' for an arbitrary function $t(n)$?

Comment: In essence: The big O notation will tell us about the relative rate of growth with $n$ but what I am interested in is some sort of absolute upper bound for an arbitrary function $t(n)$ and the value $n$ on a universal turing machine? how do i calculate it?

Comment: The actual proof of the result gives a way to construct such a family of circuits. The value of $\alpha$ depends on the turing machine deciding the problem. See Sipser *Introduction to the theory of computation* for a way to define $\alpha$ for example.

Comment: aah ok. Just to reiterate for a chosen UTM (on which we 'run' all our programs) will have the same constant $\alpha$ for all the programs? In that case for the sake of conceptual simplicity we can simply assume it as 1?

Comment: The constant $\alpha$ depends on the TM deciding the language $A$. You can't have the same UTM deciding all languages: you have to input the code $\langle M \rangle$ of the TM you are simulating, and $\alpha$ depends on $M$.

Comment: As I understand there are two parameters: 1. The worst case runtime $\langle M \rangle$ for a given size $n$ 2. The size of the program and input i.e. $|\langle M \rangle|$ and $n$. Can you please clarify how exactly does $\alpha$ depend on these? I can't find much info..?

Comment: Can you please clarify this "..$\alpha$ depends on $M$.." How exactly empirically? A formula etc. with explanation would be helpful as this was the original Q..? couldn't find it explained in Sipser..